# Inequality based on AM/GM Inequality

Tags: inequality

Find the greatest value of $x^3y^4$
If $2x+3y=7 $ and $x≥0, y≥0$.
(Probably based on weighted arithmetic and geometric mean)

Comment: Have you tried AM-GM? Where did you get stuck.

Comment: Why don't you just do substitution and then differential calculus? Looks like a straightforward problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's pretty simple if you know about weighted means, proceed like this:

$(2x/3)*3+(3y/4)*4 ≥ 7[(2x/3)^³(3y/4)^4)^{1/7}$

i.e. $7≥7((x^3y^4)(3/32))^{1/7}$

or, $(x^3y^4)(3/32)≤1$

hence, $x^3y^4≤32/3$

so $32/3$ is the greatest value of $x^3y^4$

PS: sorry for the ill written answer, I'm on phone too, my friends out there please edit the answer ;)

Comment: Your second line is based on the assumption that the LHS of the first line is $\leq 1.$

Comment: someoned did a mistake while editing it, seems legit now?

Comment: Thank you, yes it's pretty simple, silly of me

Answer (score 3):

Use this Hint:
$$7=\frac23x+\frac23x+\frac23x + \frac34y+\frac34y+\frac34y+\frac34y\geqslant 7\sqrt[7]{\cdots}$$

Comment: from your inequality how do you get the max for $x^3y^4$?

Comment: so, in this case shouldnt $\frac{2x}{3}=\frac{3y}{4}$ for max to be attained?

Comment: and how is it 5th root in the radical you mentioned?

Comment: Correct it. I am typing on a mobile.

Comment: @vidyarthi  Thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 1):

My usual attempt to generalize.

To find the max of
$x^m y^n$
subject to
$ax+by = c$
where
$m$ and  $n$
are integers.

Following
Macavity's solution,
use the
AGM inequality
in the form
$\sum_{i=1}^p a_i
\ge p (\prod_{i=1}^p a_i)^{1/p}
$.

Then

$\begin{array}\\
c
&=m\frac{ax}{m}
+n\frac{by}{n}\\
&\ge (m+n)((\frac{ax}{m})^m(\frac{by}{n})^n)^{1/(m+n)}
\qquad (m \text{ copies of }\frac{ax}{m}
\text{ and }n\text{ copies of }\frac{by}{n})\\
\end{array}
$

with equality,
by the AGM inequality,
if and only if
$\frac{ax}{m}
=\frac{by}{n}
$.

If this is true,
then
$y
=\frac{anx}{bm}
$
so

$\begin{array}\\
c
&=m\frac{ax}{m}
+n\frac{by}{n}\\
&=m\frac{ax}{m}
+n\frac{ax}{m}\\
&=ax(1+\frac{n}{m})\\
&=ax\frac{m+n}{m}\\
\end{array}
$

or
$x
=\frac{mc}{a(m+n)}
$
and
$y
=\frac{mc}{a(m+n)}\frac{an}{bm}
=\frac{nc}{b(m+n)}
$.

Finally,
$x^m y^n
=(\frac{mc}{a(m+n)})^m(\frac{nc}{b(m+n)})^n
=(\frac{m}{a})^m(\frac{n}{b})^n(\frac{c}{m+n})^{m+n}
$.

If $m+n = c$,
as in OP's case,
$x
=\frac{m}{a}
$
and
$y
=\frac{n}{b}
$
and the max is
$x^m y^n
=(\frac{m}{a})^m(\frac{n}{b})^n
$.

In this case,
$m=3, n=4, a=2, b=3, c=7$.

The result is
$x 
= \frac{3}{2}
$,
$y 
= \frac{4}{3}
$,
and the max is
$(\frac{3}{2})^3(\frac{4}{3})^4
=\frac{2^5}{3}
$.

Note that
this generalizes easily to
maximize
$\prod_{i=1}^m x_i^{n_i}
$
subject to
$c
=\sum_{i=1}^m a_ix_i
$
with
$c, n_i,$
and $a_i$
being specified.

Answer (score 1):

$y$ is a function of $x$. That is, $y=(7-2x)/3.$ And $\frac {dy}{dx}=y'=-2/3.$

Let $f(x)=x^3y^4.$ Then $f'(x)=3x^2 y^4+4x^3y^3y'=3x^2y^4-(8/3)x^3y^3.$

For $xy\ne 0$ we have $f(x)>0$ and $f'(x)=f(x)(\frac {3}{x}-\frac {8}{3y}).$

So for $xy\ne 0$ we have $f'(x)>0\iff \frac {3}{x}-\frac {8}{3y}>0\iff 9y>8x\iff21-6x>8x \iff 3/2>x.$ Similarly for $xy\ne 0$ we have $f'(x)<0\iff 3/2<x.$

And we have $xy=0\implies f'(x)=0.$

So $f(x)$ is increasing for $x<3/2$ and is decreasing for $3/2<x<7/2.$ ($7/2$ is the upper limit of the domain of $f,$ as $y=(7-2x)/3\geq 0.$) Therefore, since $f(x)$ is continuous,  $\max f=f(3/2).$

Comment: My answer disagrees with the answer from Aniket. Any comment?

Comment: Your error is here: $f(3/2)=(3/2)^3(1)^4$, which should be $f(3/2)=(3/2)^3(4/3)^4$

Comment: @grand_chat . Right. Darned  arithmetic.  :)